# jQuery UI Slider value changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is what I am trying to solve.. Essentially, I want to be able to update the value on the input when a checkbox is checked whilst using the jQuery slider ui.  So, each checkbox corresponds to a different value.  When a checkbox is checked, the value should get multiplied.

It works, but the problem is, it doesn't stayed multiplied by that number that is checked when more sliding occurs.  It goes back to the original value.

What am I doing wrong here?

HTML

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">0.10
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">0.25
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">0.5
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">0.75
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">1.00

<div class="increasedRevenue"><input id="increasedRevenueValue" value="0"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 100000,
        max: 5000000,
        step: 100000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#increasedRevenueValue").val(ui.value );

                $('input:checkbox').click(function() {

                    if($(this).is(":first-child")) {
                        $("#increasedRevenueValue").val($("#slider").slider("value") * 10);                     
                    }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the `#slider` element? I suspect it has something to do with the line `$("#increasedRevenueValue").val(ui.value );` since you're resetting it to the value stored in the `ui` object.

Comment: You might be right.  I should probably write an if else statement for the slide feature..

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here.

First, you have no values set in your checkboxes. WIthout a value how can you tell slider what mulitpier to use. The only value you are using is 10 by using the checkbox position for first checkbox only.

Next, your `step` never changes. In order to have a multiplier this would need to change, and be bound to whichever box is checked.

Next, your checkbox `click` handler should not be inside the slide event. `slide` is adding a new click handler to checkboxes for every pixel you move the slider.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWKHZ/) of your code with only difference is step is one to make easier to see changes.  See what you can do to fix some of issues I mentioned, then update the fiddle and hit `update` button to save a new version when you get as far as you possibly can

Comment: Thanks for your response, let me address your mentions one at a time:  First, I didn't set any values for my checkboxes because this an example.  Second, the step is set on the slide function, is this what you are referring to?  Thirdly, the click handler was set in the slide function originally to write a variable for ui.value.  Makes no difference where it is.  The jsfiddle created is really as far as I have gotten.  I just need to know how to make it multiply and stay that way.

Comment: I will try to help if needed... but I don't intend to write it for you. It does make a difference on clcik handler inside slide...is adding many many handlers as you move slide the slide callback gets called constantly

Comment: Really, all I am asking for is a some sort of handler I am probably missing or some sort of logic here I am not seeing.  I'll figure it out myself, nevermind.

Comment: updating `step` will be a big part of the logic.. easy to do using slider API

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I just figured it out.  Thanks to the answer Gingi gave me up top.  It's a simple if else statement that checks to see which checkbox is checked and then multiplies that value.  Simple.